# django как storage

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, архитектура

У меня предполагается база данных, постгрес. Вспомнил про существование джанго. Возникли вопросы:

- как дела с масштабированием (слышал, что плохо) на разные инстансы?
- разумно ли использовать джанго как storage к БД?
- мне потребуется сначала накатить данные в постгрес и делать это придётся не через джанго. Умеет ли такое джанго?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что значит "как storage"?

С первым вопросом  - масштабирование можно преодалеть запустив по джанге на каждом инстансе. Может использовать несколько инстансов как ридонли и один для записи. Но масштабирование разное бывает - нужны подробности.

Админка рисуется за день - два. Использую как интерфейс к небольшим проектам.

Модель можно построить средствами джанги по готовым таблицам. При создании ставится параметр `managed=False` и джанга структуру не портит.

Comment: Это значит, что как storage. RESTFulAPI

Comment: А, рест, как рест она медленная. Лучше pypika + aiohttp

Comment: Тогда у меня не одна точка входа в БД и может немного хаос быть.

Comment: postgrest скорее всего возьму

Comment: постгрест это вьюхи - много вьюх) права на уровне базы данных которые хреновенько переносятся, никакого управления схемой...